# remove control character whitespaces from dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe df by which I am getting list of list by using this

```
data = [list(map(str,n.tolist())) for n in df.values]
```

after that I replace specific control character from data like this

```
data = [ [e.replace(u'\xa0', u'') for e in tempval ] for tempval in data ]
```

This works fine but I want this to be done in dataframe itself  please suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['\xa0','s','w'],
                   'B':['s','w','v'],
                   'C':['e','d','\xa0']})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0     s  e
1  s  w  d
2  w  v
```

Then for creating `list` of `lists` convert `DataFrame` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then `tolist`:

```
df.replace(u'\xa0',u'', regex=True, inplace=True)
#if need cast all values to str add astype
print (df.astype(str).values.tolist())
[['', 's', 'e'], ['s', 'w', 'd'], ['w', 'v', '']]
```