# Can't get rid of characters in Webscraped Table in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, unicode, replace

I have scraped a table from a wikipedia page.

I want to get rid of the special characters in the country names - mostly \xa0

I found this question:
[remove control character whitespaces from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106074/remove-control-character-whitespaces-from-dataframe)
 that seemed perfect - but when I use the code, it seems to do nothing.

I suspect that is because the line not working in my code is looking for a complete field that is just the character.  How do I get the non working line to get rid of the space characters?  I don't mind using another method, or a different approach - but that just seemed so clean & efficient...

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_past_population_(United_Nations,_estimates)"
response = requests.get(url)
scraping_html_table_EQ = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
scraping_html_table_EQ = scraping_html_table_EQ.find_all("table", "wikitable")
df = pd.read_html(str(scraping_html_table_EQ))
df = df[0]

df.replace(u'\xa0',u'', regex=True, inplace=True)   #<-- line that doesn't work

df
```

Comment: what kind of error do you receive?

Comment: Not getting any error at all - that's a little bit frustrating to say the least - it all acts like it should be working but the output is still including the /xa0   If you just copy the whole code segment above and run it having already imported pandas as pd is should show you exactly what is not happenning for me...

Comment: @kiltannen - How is possible test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working (tested in `python3`) use only [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

```
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]
print (df.head())
  Country / territory     1950     1955     1960     1965     1970     1975  \
0               World  2517478  2749365  3007751  3309934  3667801  4045192   
1         Afghanistan     7752     8270     8995     9935    11121    12583   
2             Albania     1263     1420     1636     1896     2151     2411   
3             Algeria     8872     9830    11125    12627    14550    16709   
4      American Samoa       19       20       20       24       27       30   

      1980     1985     1990     1995     2000     2005     2010     2015  
0  4421695  4833180  5289294  5713824  6104538  6496776  6906374  7325929  
1    13211    11630    12068    16773    19702    24400    27962    32527  
2     2681     2967     3281     3107     3122     3082     2902     2897  
3    19338    22566    25912    28904    31184    33268    36036    39667  
4       32       39       47       53       58       59       56       56
```

If necessary first column convert to index:

```
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, index_col=0)[0]
print (df.head())

                        1950     1955     1960     1965     1970     1975  \
Country / territory                                                         
World                2517478  2749365  3007751  3309934  3667801  4045192   
Afghanistan             7752     8270     8995     9935    11121    12583   
Albania                 1263     1420     1636     1896     2151     2411   
Algeria                 8872     9830    11125    12627    14550    16709   
American Samoa            19       20       20       24       27       30   

                        1980     1985     1990     1995     2000     2005  \
Country / territory                                                         
World                4421695  4833180  5289294  5713824  6104538  6496776   
Afghanistan            13211    11630    12068    16773    19702    24400   
Albania                 2681     2967     3281     3107     3122     3082   
Algeria                19338    22566    25912    28904    31184    33268   
American Samoa            32       39       47       53       58       59   

                        2010     2015  
Country / territory                    
World                6906374  7325929  
Afghanistan            27962    32527  
Albania                 2902     2897  
Algeria                36036    39667  
American Samoa            56       56
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and got an error - ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it  Is pd.read_html a Python 3 feature?

Comment: @kiltannen - hmmm, hard question. I really dont know :(

Comment: Its looking like I need to install the htnl5lib - working on it now.  Will report back shortly

Comment: @kiltannen - Super, I am curious.

Comment: OK - I can report that for some reason i did need to install the HTML5LIB package - I would have thought it was a component of BeautifulSoup but it seems not.  After installing that BeautifulSoup broke! *bugger* says I!  So I reinstall BeautifulSoup - gives me the chance to upgrade it to the latest version anyway... restart my Jupyter notebook - and I'm AWAY!  Using this method it came in perfectly cleanly!  Thank you!    I will share this method with my lecturer - and why I asked the question - and hopefully this will help others in the future...

Comment: NOW - I suspect I will need to ask another question tomorrow - I need to find a method to "fill in" the missing years, but I have to sleep now and then I have work tomorrow.  So I'll begin researching/ figuring out how to do that sometime tomorrow.  I ALSO just figured out you gave an expanded answer! You anticipated the need to make the first column an index - this was just excellent coaching on your part - once again - THANK YOU!  If I could upvote you twice and marked it as resolved twice I would!